# Voice over is skipping the cell in forward swipe?

Tags: swift, uitableview, voiceover

I have a screen where i designed with table view,voice over not reading last cell in farward swipe,it reads with back swipe only and if it is visible then only.can anyone please guide how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.